# Bitwise Operator

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, shift

public class UnsignedShift {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char hex[] = new char[] {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};


    byte b = (byte) 0xf1;
    byte d = (byte)(b>>>4); 


    System.out.println("b>>>4=0x" + hex[(d>>4)&0x0f] + hex[d&0x0f]);

    }
```

}

The result = 0xff

can anyone explain how it is possible in Java?

I think,it is 0x0f

Answer (score 1):

There are no binary operators in java that can operate directly with bytes (8 bits). Variables of type byte, short or char automatically suffer a "numeric promotion" to a 32 bit integer before operations like these are performed as detailed in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).
So here is what happens in your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char hex[] = new char[] {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};

    byte b = (byte) 0xf1;    // b is a byte with 0xf1
    byte d = (byte)(b>>>4);  // b is converted to int, becoming 0xfffffff1 then shifted
                             // to the right by 4 bits, resulting in 0x0fffffff

    System.out.println("b>>>4=0x" + hex[(d>>4)&0x0f] + hex[d&0x0f]);

}
```

If you want to get that right its just easier to use 32 bit variables for all binary operations, like in the example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       char hex[] = new char[] {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};

        byte b = (byte) 0xf1;
        int ib = b & 0xff;
        byte d = (byte)(ib>>>4); 

        System.out.println("b>>>4=0x" + hex[(d>>4)&0x0f] + hex[d&0x0f]);
}
```

Note: Just in case you don't know, you can easily print an integer number in the hexadecimal format by calling `Integer.toHexString(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

> byte b = (byte) 0xf1  will be 1111 0001
>
> byte d = (byte)(b>>>4) will be 1111 1111
>
> d>>4 will be  11111111
>
> 0x0f will be  00001111
>
> (d>>4)&0x0f will be  00001111 == 15
>
> d will be 11111111
>
> 0f  will be 00001111
>
> hex[d&0x0f] will be 00001111  == 15
>
> So Final Answer : 0xff

I think you are expecting (byte)(b>>>4) to shift 0 from left to right 4 times. But b is an integer with 32 bits, it will move 4 bytes from left but get ignored by (byte) conversion. byte conversion take 8 least significant bits of an integer.